# NodeJS Array of objects into one Object

Tags: node.js

I have the following structure

```
[
  { type: 'total_users', total: '393647' },
  { type: 'total_male_users', total: '259555' },
  { type: 'total_female_users', total: '134092' },
  { type: 'active_users', total: '1232' },
  { type: 'active_male_users', total: '144' }
]
```

I'm trying to convert this into an object (something like the following)... I would like to reference the object like "blah.total_users"

```
{
  'total_users': '393647',
  'total_male_users',
  'total_female_users',
  'active_users',
  'active_male_users'
}
```

Being trying the following but I'm a way off - returns an array and errors with the return structure below.

```
statistics = statisticsResult.rows.map((data) => [data.type]: data.total)
```

thankyou

Comment: map will return another array.. if you want to change array to object, you can do it using reduce function (instead of map function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arr.reduce (instead of arr.map, because map will return an array) to do this, for ex:

```
const arr = [
  { type: 'total_users', total: '393647' },
  { type: 'total_male_users', total: '259555' },
  { type: 'total_female_users', total: '134092' },
  { type: 'active_users', total: '1232' },
  { type: 'active_male_users', total: '144' }
];

const x = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.type] = cur.total;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with [lodash](https://lodash.com/), using [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#assign) or [defaults()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#defaults).

Which you use is dependent on the behavior you want.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
[
  { type: 'total_users', total: '393647' },
  { type: 'total_male_users', total: '259555' },
  { type: 'total_female_users', total: '134092' },
  { type: 'active_users', total: '1232' },
  { type: 'active_male_users', total: '144' }
];

const obj = _.assign( {}, ...arr );
```